# ValueError: Invalid placeholder when running python script

Tags: python, batch-file, environment-variables

I have a python script that changes the environment variables in a batch script and writing new batch files. The batch files in turn changes the environment variables in another file and write new files.
In my python script, I have the following code:

```
TEMPLATE_PATH = "/home/eric2207/test/data_template.cmd"

    def specialise_cmd(template, things_to_replace, outfile):
            with open(TEMPLATE_PATH, "r") as f:
                    template = string.Template(f.read())
                    cmd = template.substitute(things_to_replace)

            with open(outfile, "w") as f:
                    f.write(cmd)

    for k in range (0, len(atomic_mass)):

            replace_dict = {"i" : atomic_mass[k]}

            cmd_name = "/home/eric2207/data/Z=66/data_{0}.cmd".format(atomic_mass[k])
            specialise_cmd(TEMPLATE_PATH, replace_dict, cmd_name)
```

In data_template.cmd, the code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -q parallel
#PBS -l walltime=00:24:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=6

input="/home/eric2207/dir.dat"
output="/home/eric2207/DRHBc/dir.dat"

${i}
deformation=("-0.40" "-0.20" "0.00" "0.20" "0.40" "0.60")

cd /home/eric2207/data/Z=66
mkdir DY"${i}"

for j in "${deformation[@]}"
do
        cd /home/eric2207/DRHBc
        make clean
        sed -e "s/\${A}/${i}/" -e "s/\${beta}/$j/" $input > $output
        make
        cd /home/eric2207/data/Z=66/DY"${i}"
        mkdir ./"$j"
        cd ./"$j"
        cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc/1drhbws .
        cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc/dir.dat .
        cp /home/eric2207/DRHBc/paramet.for .
done
```

In the dir.dat file, I have the environment variables ${A} and ${beta}.
When running the python script, I received the error of invalid placeholder for all the variables in data_template.cmd except for i.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "multiple.py", line 43, in <module>
        specialise_cmd(TEMPLATE_PATH, replace_dict, cmd_name)
      File "multiple.py", line 13, in specialise_cmd
        cmd = template.substitute(things_to_replace)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/string.py", line 172, in substitute
        return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/string.py", line 169, in convert
        self._invalid(mo)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/string.py", line 146, in _invalid
        (lineno, colno))
ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 15, col 11
```

However, I need those placeholders in data_template.cmd to change the environment variables in dir.dat. I am wondering what is going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As an FYI, `#!/bin/sh` is for Bourne Shell (in Linux), not for windows batch files. Consider not including this (called a shebang) in future.

Comment: Hi @Modelmat, I tried changing the cmd file into a shell script. The same error persists.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It appears that you were writing a shell script already. This is not a batch script, please do not refer to it as such. It would be helpful to receive the full traceback too.

Comment: @Modelmat, the traceback is now added to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Python 2.6 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/string.html#template-strings) state,

> Any other appearance of $ in the string will result in a ValueError being raised.

`$` appears in line 15, col 11 (as specified in your error.)
This is `for j in "${deformation[@]}"`. Your script cannot contain this.

I would recommend the script being ported to python, as you are already using it. Take a look at the [os.mkdir()](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.mkdir) and the [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.system) functions to get started.

Comment: So you mean, eliminate the usage of the shell script and do everything in the python script?

Comment: Yes, preferably. You could do entirely shell script, or manually replace strings, but that is the way I would recommend.

Comment: If this is the answer you're looking for, please mark it so.